# HTML parse with perl get rid of inline css styles

Tags: html, css, perl, parsing

I have this file that I get from a wget.

```
casperadm@casper:~> cat /tmp/one
<html>
<head>
<style>
a{text-decoration:none}
a:link{color:024C7E}
a:visited{color:024C7E}
a:active{color:958600}
body{font:10pt verdana;text-align:justify}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
x
-----
casper foo text
</body>
</html>
```

and then I built a very simple HTML parse in Perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings ;
use strict;

package HTMLStrip;
use base "HTML::Parser";

  subtext {
     my ($self, $text) = @_;
     print $text;
  }

  my $p = new HTMLStrip;
  # parse line-by-line, rather than the whole file at once
  while (<>) {
      $p->parse($_);
  }
 # flush and parse remaining unparsed HTML
  $p->eof;
```

The parsing works fine, however, it seems to ignore the inline stylings which were unexpected error and is screwing up my data collections of the older web pages that I have to get data from. 
Any ideas on how to get rid of the smooth inline CSS stylings?

```
casperadm@casper:~> /tmp/pleaseParse /tmp/one
a{text-decoration:none}a:link{color:024C7E}a:visited{color:024C7E}a:active{color:958600}body{font:10pt verdana;text-align:justify}
x
-----
casper foo text
```

Comment: BTW, *"parse line-by-line, rather than the whole file at once"* - why? HTML tags can be split across multiple lines, `"<div\nclass\n=\n'foo'\n>"` is valid HTML.

Comment: I was taught not to suck in file all at once - because it takes up too much memory - however in this case, you might be right.  It is just a habit.

Comment: Have you tried `HTML::TreeBuilder` from [HTML::Tree](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Tree)?

Comment: HTML:: Tree is not installed on the company network. Gotta work with what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HTML::TreeBuilder` from [HTML::Tree](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Tree):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;
my $parser = HTML::TreeBuilder->new()
    or die "can't create parser\n";

my $root = $parser->parse_file(\*DATA)
    or die "can't parse HTML\n";

#$root->dump();
my $style = $root->look_down(_tag => 'style')
    or die "can't find <style>!\n";

$style->dump();

# IMPORTANT: needs to be deleted() if you continue your code!
$root->delete();

exit 0;

__DATA__
<html>
<head>
<style>
a{text-decoration:none}
a:link{color:024C7E}
a:visited{color:024C7E}
a:active{color:958600}
body{font:10pt verdana;text-align:justify}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
x
-----
casper foo text
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
<style> @0.0.0
  "\x0aa{text-decoration:none}\x0aa:link{color:024C7E}\x0aa:visited{color:024..."
```

Use the [HTML::Element](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Element) methods to manipulate the DOM node `$style` points to.